# i have created 3 tables in sql for solving queries using join

Tags: sql, join

The following is table details which I got for my class test:

- `Book` (title (primary key), bname, author, publisher, price)
- `Distributor` (distid (primary key), dname, city)
- `Orders` (Ono (primary key), title (foreign key), distid (foreign key), quantity)

I have created above tables

Now I have to solve following queries

1. Create a view showing distributor name who are supplying author JK rowling’s Book,
2. Show order details for all 1 books(solve by subquery)

Please help me to solve above queries and please tell me which join I can use and how to use it

To solve above queries.

Comment: Question #2 is not too clear to me, can you elaborate?  Question #1 is just a `JOIN` across all three tables with a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to part #1:

```
SELECT d.dname
FROM Distributer d INNER JOIN Orders o
ON d.distid = o.distid
INNER JOIN Book b
ON o.title = b.title
WHERE b.author = 'JK Rowling'
```